# Do we have to upload different resolutions icons in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

Android requires 5 different resolution of images and ios requires 3 different resolution of images during development.

Does unity requires different resolutions of images while building for android or   ios?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **NO**. But it's way more complicated than that.

On unity, you can always submit your icon once and it will resize to each required size on each platform you'd like to publish your app. You can see that on player settings. Build Settings > Player Settings > Icon. You can also submit your own custom icon for each platform selecting the checkbox "Override for ...", there you can submit different sizes for each platform.

Now comes the tricky part. During the last four years, I've published 7 games and I **ALWAYS** had problems with icons on iOS and XCode. When publishing your game to iOS, *I never tested the cloud build* but whenever you build your game to iOS locally, you'll be prompt with a Xcode file that you have to edit before building for profiling and archiving which will allow you to publish your game to iTunes Connect. This is the part where I constantly have problems. I didn't test the new 2017 version but before that, some required icon sizes were not filled correctly so you had to go and drag from your computer. It's better to be ready to, MAYBE, fill some icon sizes yourself.

Another thing you might notice is that on store listing, you might have problems with icon sizes too. For example: For your google play listing, you'll require a 512x512 icon. For your iTunes Connect, you'll require a 1024x1024 icon and for Windows Phone, much like apple, you'll require all sorts of icon sizes. The same goes for screenshots.

*But TL:DR: For Unity, you can always submit your icon once and Unity will resize it for each platform and required size you need. You can check that under Build Settings > Player Settings > Icon*

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I am a beginner in unity so please help me.
I want to know that like in android we have to provide 5 different resolution images (xxxhdpi,xxhdpi,xhdpi,and so on)for development using android studio.

But how does unity handles different resolution images?
As far as i know unity  accepts only one image not multiple resolutions of images.

Comment: You can choose to fill many icon resolutions under Build Settings > Player Settings > Icon and selecting the checkbox that says Override for Android. Then you'll see the boxes with different sizes. You can also submit the largest and unity will resize it. Unity's icon resize is pretty good and I often submit one icon and use it as default for every platform I'm deploying. Never had any kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

Does this concept work for game sprites also?(not game icon but the ingame images/sprites)

I mean how unity manages game sprites for multiple resolutions while building for android?

Comment: Game sprites are not resized, however, you should be careful when creating it because, in Unity, sprites will always be loaded to the closest "2" multiplier. That means if you have a 56x56 sprite, Unity will load your sprite on your graphics video board as a 64x64 sprite. That can get really out of hand if you just create sprite randomly, let's say a "background" image that's 1360x720, this image will be loaded your graphics board as a 2048x2048 image.

Comment: Usefull information thanks man.

And how we manage sprites for multiple resolution ?

For example - if we import a 2048×2048 background sprites which will not be suitable for every resolution. I know we can stretch it to the canvas but whats the point of showing a 2048×2048 image on a 1024×1024 resolution phone.

Comment: I mean is there any way to manage that sprite(2048×2048) for multiple resolution phone

Comment: @VitorFigueredo I know that this post is a couple of years old, but there are 2 things that I need to point out, first: you can tell unity not to resize a sprite to the nearest power of 2, and second, your example would resize to 1024x512 as those are the nearest powers of 2.